# Microphone crackling

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, microphone

I have an issue with microphone. When I speak others can hear crackling, I tried different settings in alsamixer and also tried to play a little bit with PulseEffects but none of these two helped. Also tried different Linux distributions .. Ubuntu and Pop OS. I still can hear the crackling when I test it on Discord for example.

Microphone and sound card are okay. Tested back on Windows 10 and it worked well.

lspci | grep "Audio"

```
0b:00.3 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
```

Did anyone have the same issue or do you know how to solve it? Would really appreciate it.

UPDATE: I fixed it by buying USB sound card. Not optimal solution but it works.

Comment: Is it an external microphone or is it built-in?

Comment: @NiallJones external microphone

Comment: I have the same issue. Just bought a Thinkpad T495

Comment: Well that is pretty unfortunate since you have a notebook. I solved it using USB-C docking station with dedicated audio jack. But still did not found any solution for the sound card.

Answer (score 0):

Since the hardware works fine on your Windows 10, I would say this is most likely a sound card driver issue.
You should check the sound card model and see if there's any drivers available for your linux distribution.

A quick search on google shows there's a lot of users with *similar* problems with the same kind of hardware: [1](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=294344), [2](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=238678), [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114041/ubuntu-18-04-sound-doesnt-work-dummy-output), [4](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=272955).

If you can't find the solution, you might be better off asking the question in [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) and providing them with more information. Good luck!

Comment: I did not find the solution but finally found related thread on some forum, where they discuss my issue however it is not still resolved.. USB sound seems to be an only option.

Comment: OK, let us know if you manage to solve the problem, also you can link the thread you found - it might be useful for someone else in the future.

Comment: My bad.. Here you are: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195303 .. I fixed it using USB-C docking station which I usually use for laptop but as temp. solution it works just fine.